# Suggested reading list: OS exploits

Tags: operating-systems, exploit, buffer-overflow, professional-education

In computer security, my areas of interest include x86 processors, binary exploitation and reverse engineering. I'm also interested in the certain aspects of the minix and the linux kernel(memory management, filesystems).

A book I read recently is The Shellcoders handbook. I would like suggestions on books which you have read and would recommend to others. Suggestions could be platform independent, thanks!

Please note: I have asked the same question at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056703/suggested-reading-list-security) and have received two really good responses. I am still looking for more suggestions, hence, am posting it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interests are very similar to mine (except reverse engineering);
Here is a list of the books I have next to me right now:

- Understanding the Linux Kernel 3rd ed.
- Gray Hat Hacking 3rd ed.
- The Shellcoders Handbook 2nd ed.
- Linux Kernel Development 3rd ed
- Hacking: The Art of Exploitation 2nd ed
- Attacking the Core: A Guide to Kernel Exploitation
- The Art of Software Security Assessment

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend reading "[Gray Hat Hacking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072257091)"  by Harper et al. (3rd ed.)

But more importantly, I would recommend **doing** exercises rather than reading about them.  Perhaps start at overthewire.org and do vortex there.  The exercises cover all of your areas of interest and they contain links to a lot of on-line reading.

Answer (score 1):

See my question here:

[Reverse engineering malware/viruses](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/reverse-engineering-malware-viruses)

There were some very good answers with a few links to some very good resources for reading. Most of which made it to my Amazon wish list.

Answer (score 1):

Even if one is not interested specifically in Mac OS X exploitation, I would recommend [The Mac Hackers Handbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470395362) for reading. Probably major amount of this book is OS specific, but it's written very well - described methodologies, techniques to find and exploit bugs can be applied everywhere in appropriate subject. Also, it's just interesting to read because it contains a lot of real-life examples, you won't be bored.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the vein of topics you are most interested in, and quite think, but "The Rootkit Arsenal" by the Reverend Bill Blunden is an excellent read.